# Unable to cast object to GenericList

Tags: c#

The below line of code is giving an exception:

```
listEmpFullDetails = (List<EmployeeListVM>)listEmpFullDetails.Skip(start).Take(pageSize);
```

Exception received:

> Unable to cast object of type 'd__251[ess.Model.Common.EmployeeListVM]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just cast this an iterator to a list. Instead, simply chain a `.ToList()` at the end, so:

```
listEmpFullDetails = listEmpFullDetails
    .Skip(start)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```